# xamarin forms android, Font asset not found sans-serif-medium when switching to AppShell

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I am attempting to code an App in Xamarin Forms.

Upon startup, if the app is logged in the the user will be taken to the main shell with flyouts etc. If they are not logged in, then they will be taken to the signup/login page.

I have the following code in my App.xaml.cs

```
    public App()
    {
        Instance = this;
        InitializeComponent();
                    
        AssessStartupPage();
    }


    public void AssessStartupPage()
    {
        if (App.LoggedInUser == null)
        {
            SwitchToSignupPage_OTP();
            return;
        }
        SwitchToShell();
    }

    public void SwitchToSignupPage_OTP() => SwitchMainView(new SignupPage_OTP());
    public void SwitchToShell() => SwitchMainView(new AppShell());
```

When I attempt to switch to the shell from another Page (by calling App.Instance.SwitchToShell) the following exception is thrown:

> Java.Lang.RuntimeException
> Font asset not found sans-serif-medium

However if I change the AssessStartupPage() function which is called on startup to this:

```
    public void AssessStartupPage()
    {
        SwitchToShell();
        return;         
    }
```

The shell loads correctly at startup. However I need to be able to have the Signup page load at start if the user is not signed in and therefore need to be able to switch to the shell once signup is complete.

I have updated all the xamarin forms and xamarin essential libraries to the latest stable version but nothing seems to help.

The problem doesn't occur when I debug the app in UWP mode.

Comment: Do you use custom font in your code? If so, you could check if Fonts/sans-serif-medium exists in project.

Comment: @JianweiSun-MSFT I do not use any custom fonts in my code

Comment: Well, it's probably an issue. You can check this: ['Font asset not found sans-serif' as a FirstChanceException](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/13601). It's a little weird. And if it's ok, could you provide some more code so that I can reproduce the situation you described.